# How to convert bytes to dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

I need to convent bytes to dict.

I requested some content from a website and got back a bytes list as a response. I need is as a dict to parse it.

My code:

```
import ast

data= requests.get('blahblahblah.com')
```

**The data received in bytes looks like this:**

```
b'{"response": {"message": null, "data": [{"friendly_name": "Local", "user_id": 0}, {"friendly_name": "cinematopiamedia2", "user_id": 25431133}, {"friendly_name": "Aknight2015", "user_id": 23505515}, {"friendly_name": "aloyisunique", "user_id": 7332509}, {"friendly_name": "Alwaysbhere", "user_id": 23060332}, {"friendly_name": "Bastarded", "user_id": 25476710}, {"friendly_name": "bellmatsu", "user_id": 11768932}, {"friendly_name": "Calibear14", "user_id": 22882269}, {"friendly_name": "cbjay45820@gmail.com", "user_id": 25740986}, {"friendly_name": "ChocoboBurger", "user_id": 24689117}, {"friendly_name": "CrayPharma", "user_id": 14869791}, {"friendly_name": "cree23", "user_id": 24241253}, {"friendly_name": "crystaljock", "user_id": 24618156}, {"friendly_name": "dared24", "user_id": 25194790}, {"friendly_name": "DarkWolfNine", "user_id": 1132520}, {"friendly_name": "DennyCrane12", "user_id": 20646060}, {"friendly_name": "devharding", "user_id": 24244101}, {"friendly_name": "ElJeppy", "user_id": 11420141}, {"friendly_name": "emilstricker", "user_id": 268195}, {"friendly_name": "fjones1979", "user_id": 36905}, {"friendly_name": "frikkels123", "user_id": 12222188}, {"friendly_name": "graciesusan", "user_id": 24818998}, {"friendly_name": "Greenwo0d", "user_id": 1548410}, {"friendly_name": "grttinp", "user_id": 20628044}, {"friendly_name": "Hassled1", "user_id": 2877418}, {"friendly_name": "imdragon", "user_id": 13954870}, {"friendly_name": "iviogle08@gmail.com", "user_id": 17549794}, {"friendly_name": "jay.tyu", "user_id": 14055795}, {"friendly_name": "jefnull", "user_id": 3303610}, {"friendly_name": "jingkoo", "user_id": 14512376}, {"friendly_name": "jkind73", "user_id": 179199}, {"friendly_name": "jojoplatinum", "user_id": 25436659}, {"friendly_name": "jumur", "user_id": 24982579}, {"friendly_name": "kantarin", "user_id": 21578150}, {"friendly_name": "Killfury13", "user_id": 283266}, {"friendly_name": "licquyd", "user_id": 10814806}, {"friendly_name": "LinuxOS", "user_id": 25246528}, {"friendly_name": "login123", "user_id": 9769776}, {"friendly_name": "Lokanas", "user_id": 8194426}, {"friendly_name": "Looser2786", "user_id": 24536524}, {"friendly_name": "mcmcguirl", "user_id": 3138953}, {"friendly_name": "ndiniwacho", "user_id": 1534152}, {"friendly_name": "nemethmm", "user_id": 3196505}, {"friendly_name": "nicholasalan126", "user_id": 4627399}, {"friendly_name": "ossinova", "user_id": 6572284}, {"friendly_name": "Phoenixfighter65", "user_id": 24399546}, {"friendly_name": "Pirate_321", "user_id": 23574312}, {"friendly_name": "poplida", "user_id": 18469171}, {"friendly_name": "Quzehh", "user_id": 4026309}, {"friendly_name": "RubberDucky25", "user_id": 23209468}, {"friendly_name": "saotome128", "user_id": 16655435}, {"friendly_name": "scatterscott", "user_id": 1080098}, {"friendly_name": "sfaze", "user_id": 24123475}, 
{"friendly_name": "shawnieb", "user_id": 346644}, {"friendly_name": "Sid87", "user_id": 25570077}, {"friendly_name": "SilentSlayerOWI", "user_id": 13376510}, {"friendly_name": "SpeedyAus", "user_id": 23313023}, {"friendly_name": "Srmouzon", "user_id": 22870338}, {"friendly_name": "StandardSushi", "user_id": 24112439}, {"friendly_name": "tatui101", "user_id": 23966159}, {"friendly_name": "TPSeer", "user_id": 19499153}, {"friendly_name": "treyseaboldt", "user_id": 13511995}, {"friendly_name": "tripredagus", "user_id": 25044787}, {"friendly_name": "tulpam16", "user_id": 24237322}, {"friendly_name": "underlow", "user_id": 15606369}, {"friendly_name": "WhiteBoy84", "user_id": 21068833}, {"friendly_name": "wyofreeride", "user_id": 3727029}, {"friendly_name": "Zoophy", "user_id": 3835968}], 
"result": "success"}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use requests's `.json()`:

```
requests.get('blahblahblah.com').json()
```